# schengen visa application for the second one

Tags: visas, schengen

I have a Schengen visa valid until the 8th of July and I want to apply for a visa from the 12th of July is that possible or would they refuse it?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible.

- Generally speaking, any short, successful visit (no overstays, no incidents) will increase the chances that you will get another one.
- If you apply for a long visit directly after a previous one, that decreases your chances since there are fewer ties to your home country. The 90/180 rule would apply to any combination of C visa, too.
- You are supposed to apply from your place of residence, and time might be short to get things done before July 12th.

Comment: thank you very much,
 do you think if i apply tommorro as i have everything required will be enough to get it ?

Comment: I can't possibly know, that depends on your nationality, place of residence, and what they have in their files. However, 16 working days is very little time for a visa.

Comment: thank you .. still hope it works my last visa toke 9 working days .. i am iraqi student at the uni of manchester uk .. i have everything they asked for so hopefully it wouldn't take that long